# Fourth Normal Form

Tags: database-normalization

Fourth Normal Form describes a relation that is in BCNF but that also contains no non-trivial multivalued dependencies.

How do I identify trivial multivalued dependencies and non-trivial multivalued dependencies in order to normalize to 4NF?

Comment: "Fourth Normal Form describes a relation that is in BCNF but one that also contains no non-trivial multivalued dependencies." No, it does not.

Answer (score 5):

There is a fairly good example on wikipedia: [Fourth normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/4NF). Is there any specific part you don't understand?

You might also want to look at [Multivalued dependency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivalued_dependency).

**UPDATE:** *so what is the difference between trivial and non trivial dependencies?*

It depends if we are talking about functional or multivalued dependencies.

A trivial functional dependency `X -> Y` is one where **`Y` is a subset of `X`**. Since `X -> Y` means "Y can be determined from X", this is trivially true for any `X` and `Y` where `Y` is made up of attributes from `X`; obviously if we know `X` we can determine `Y` if it only contains stuff from `X`!

A trivial multivalued dependency `X ->-> Y` is one where **`Y` contains every attribute not in `X`**. Note it can also contain attributes in `X` as well. This kind of multivalued dependency is also true for all `X` and `Y` and is therefore trivial. This follows from the definition of multivalued dependency:

> *denote by (x,y,z) the tuple having
>   values for `X`, `Y`, `R − X − Y`
>   collectively equal to x, y, z,
>   correspondingly, then whenever the
>   tuples (a,b,c) and (a,d,e) exist in r,
>   the tuples (a,b,e) and (a,d,c) should
>   also exist in r.*

In a trivial multivalued dependancy, the set `z = R - X - Y` is empty, so the requirement reduces to ( `0` being the empty set):

> *tuples (a,b,0) and (a,d,0) exist in r,
>   the tuples (a,b,0) and (a,d,0) should
>   also exist in r.*

Which is obviously true.

Comment: Re your comments: All attributes are dependent on all CKs all the time since a CK is a superkey. Every relation has at least one CK. You are getting definitions wrong. It's not clear what you are trying to say. BCNF is, every determinant of a non-trivial FD is a superkey. Under BCNF there can certainly be non-prime attributes.

Comment: "A trivial multivalued dependency X ->-> Y is one where Y contains every attribute not in X." That is false. (Your adding more can't undo that.) The MVD article doesn't give a definition. It says "A multivalued dependency X ↠ Y is trivial if Y is a subset of X, or if X ∪ Y is the whole set of attributes of the relation." Since it uses "if", that's not a definition. Changing the "if" to "iff" gives a correct definition. The article glossary does not give a definition. An MVD is trivial when/iff it is either what the article calls a trivial MVD 1 or what it calls a trivial MVD 2.

Comment: (Consequently) "In a trivial multivalued dependancy, the set z = R - X - Y is empty" is also false. Also, the final quote, which is not a quote but your having replaced c by 0 in a quote, does not make sense, since in the original c is a value that is an element of a 3-tuple.

Answer (score 1):

X->Y is Trival if and only if the right hand side is a subset of the left hand side.
X->Y is Non Trival if Y is not contained in X.

Comment: These are FDs, the question is about MVDs.